# npm faker issue in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, faker

In angular project I am creating two files to generate fake data.

File structure as below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBSFQ.png

Writing generate.js to create data into database.json

And creating command in package.json as below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIj6t.png

But am getting errors while running code as "npm run generate"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/70c2M.png

FYI : I tried deleting node modules and regerating them but not able to get solution

````
var database = { products: []};

for (var i = 1; i<= 300; i++) {
  database.products.push({
    id: i,
    name: faker.commerce.productName(),
    description: faker.lorem.sentences(),
    price: faker.commerce.price(),
    imageUrl: "https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?product",
    quantity: faker.random.number()
  });
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(database)); ```
````

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @gre_gor Sure, Got it. Thanks will count this now on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using faker@6.6.6 latest version then it's not going to be work because developer closed this project with last commit of [endgame](https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/) but if you want to use fakerjs then downgrade your package by faker@5.5.3 then its going to work like

```
npm i faker@5.5.3
```